# why we can't access elements stored in a string after \0?

Tags: c, string

I wrote this program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char s[]="hi\0h";
for(int i=0 ;i<4;i++)
printf("s[%d] = %c\n", i ,s[i]); // gives 4 chars 'h'-'i'-''-'h'
printf("%s", s);   // output : hi
return 0;
}
```

Why the program does not show us the character string stored after \0 although it may contain an important message?
And why the function strlen(s) gives us 2(the length of s) while there are more then 2 characters ?

Comment: Strings end at `\0` by definition.

Comment: because c uses [asciiz strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

Comment: yes , i know that strings end at \0 , but why it still stoke more chars after \0 that we can chek using a for loop ?

Comment: and i have a problem about the lenght of the stirng !!

Comment: because `s` is array, you can access all elements of array, but if you consider it as string - then it is 2 symbol string

Comment: You can still access `h` after the first `\0`. Functions like `printf("%s"...)` or `puts()` or from `string.h` like `strlen()` will stop at the first `'\0'`.

Comment: You are confusing byte arrays with strings.  By definition, strings end at the first null byte.  You can use `sizeof(s)` to find the total length of the byte array `s` including the second null byte.  You have to know what's beyond the first null byte to be able to access it reliably.

Comment: TheKing, research _string literal_ vs. _string_.  `"hi\0h"` is a string literal.

Comment: Try this **only** at home: `char onetwothree[] = "one\0two\0three"; printf("%s %s %s\n", onetwothree, onetwothree + 4, onetwothree + 8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, an array is a contiguous sequence of elements of one type (C 2018 6.2.5 20) and a string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character (C 2018 7.1.1 1).

Fundamentally, an array is memory the program uses for whatever purposes it wishes, and a string is particular data inside an array that is used in conjunction with the standard library routines and other routines written to use strings.

Strings end at a null character because it is useful to have routines that work with such strings. It gives programmers simple ways to print strings, concatenate strings, search strings for characters, and otherwise work with strings. It is not always the best way, but it is easy to use for many elementary purposes. For example, sometimes it is better to have a separate record of the length of a string so that we do not need to go to the effort of figuring out string length by examining all its characters.

Strings must be inside arrays, because a string is, by definition, a contiguous sequence of characters, and contiguous sequences of things appear in arrays. An array still has all its elements even if the string currently inside it ends before the end of the array, and you can always access those elements by their array indices, regardless of the length of the string. However, library routines that work with strings will not care about the data beyond the end of the string.

If you want to work with data in an array beyond the end of the string, you can write source code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the program does not show us the character string stored after \0 although it may contain an important message?

Code did not attempt to print the character *string* stored after `\0`.

Code printed 4 of the 5 characters of the *string literal* `"hi\0h"` with the below code:

```
for(int i=0 ;i<4;i++)
  printf("s[%d] = %c\n", i ,s[i]);
```

Code then printed the first *string* of the *string literal* `"hi\0h"`:

```
printf("%s", s);
```

---

`"hi\0h"` is a 5 character *string literal* made up of 5 `char`: `'h'`, `'i'`, `'\0'`, `'h'`, `'\0'`.  It consists of a *string* followed by another a *string*.

`"%s"` directs `printf()` to take the address of the *string* and print characters until a *null character* is read, so only `'h'` and `'i'` are printed.

`"%s"` does *not* direct `printf()` to take the address of the *string literal* and print all its characters.

---

To print all the characters of a *string literal*, use a loop.

```
for(size_t i=0 ;i<sizeof("hi\0h"); i++)
  printf("[%zu] = '%c'\n", i ,"hi\0h"[i]);
```

In C library:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.